# How do you sucessfuly use the uninstaller for Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot

I tried Ubuntu, and I find that I am not using it.  I would like to use the uninstaller provided by the installation program but I cannot seem to get it to work. I am not a programmer and have limited ability with C prompt commands. At the very least I would like to change the boot order, and will be darned if I cannot remember which F key to press! I run windows 7

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the ubuntu partition from within `Windows` then fix `MBR` using windows repair disk or instsller.

Here is [a tutorial](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-safely-uninstall-ubuntu-in-windows-dual-boot-environment/) for your need.